# How do I get memory information of jvm cluster

Tags: java, unix, aix

I have to display jvm memory usage data on a page. I need to find the jvm memory stats such as free memory and max memory.

java runtime functions give data only of one jvm. How do I find this for a jvm cluster consisting of 4 jvms.

If possible it could be a unix command or some java function.

Comment: periodically poll each jvm via jmx - or use a tool/service such as newrelic

Answer (score 1):

since JVM doesnt support clustering out of the box. (assuming you are referring to the standard oracle distribution) 
you will have to develop an aggregation of JVM memory stats from different JVMs .

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "jvm cluster" since JVMs can't really be clustered. Ie, there is no clustering capability in the JVM itself.

Programs (themselves running on a jvm) can be clustered using a third party tool or library (or by writing the relevant code yourself, which I would advise against).

This means that, since there is no core-jdk support for clustering, there is also no java function call that can give certain values for the cluster. The software/tool/library you are using to cluster your program *might* be able to give this information but you'd have to look that up in the documentation.

For the same reason, there's also no unix call. *nix OSes know nothing about your java cluster, they just know that there are processes running on them that use the CPU and memory and probably do some I/O. They have no idea about any clustering and therefore can not help you with your question.

So, to find what you are looking for:

- If it's a true  scaling cluster, ie the workload gets automatically divided over the different jvms in the cluster, you'd have to take a look at the documentation for the clustering software (tool/library) you use to find out if they can give you that information.
- If you use a third party application (such as Zabbix) to monitor different JVMs you might construct a screen or view which can show you the data for multiple JVMs in one screen. Again, you'd have to look this up in the documentation for that tool.